# MongoDB Security

Tags: security, mongodb

I'm looking for "Security Best Practices" for a MongoDB Server, apart from "general" server's security best practices. Could you point me to useful resources?

Comment: There is excellent info in the answers below. I often find questions closed as "not constructive" which have info I couldn't easily find without the help of those who have aggregated it here. I want to say "don't be discouraged when questions you ask or answer get closed." I think there are a lot of over-zealous closures and closers. I answer a lot of `bash` questions and can tell you there is never a *best* way/answer, but those questions never get closed.

Answer (score 10):

What basically needs to be done is

**Enable Authentication**

Open mongoDB shell

```
use admin
db.addUser("admin","adminpassword")
```

( IMPORTANT: you will need an admin user before you enable authentication, or else you will loose access to data ).

Now edit the mongodb config file
`sudo vi /etc/mongodb.conf`

and uncomment `auth=true`. Save it and restart mongo db `sudo service mongodb restart`

**Bind mongoDB to trusted network or machine**

Edit mongoDB config file and add `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` or a comma separated list of IPs that will be able to connect to mongoDB. Then restart.

For more information you can find a guide to do these on my website [here](http://quadloops.com/guide-to-securing-mongodb/)

Comment: This answer is really quite borderline, in my opinion; it's self-promotional, and does not really include any information of value here, on this site. Finally, you have neglected to include the required disclosure that it is your site to which you are linking. I am adding that disclosure here; **Do not forget that disclosure in the future**, please.

Comment: Sure I'll do this next time .

Answer (score 7):

Security concerns are always specific to an application.  Its really not possible to fully answer this question in a general way.

Often times applications that rely upon a NOSQL databases will be susceptible to [OWASP A4 -  Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).  It should be noted that the `_ID` value isn't a cryptographic nonce,  this value is heavily dependent on a timestamp and there for its pretty easy for an attacker to guess these values.

Another common problem is [CWE-602 - client side enforcement of server side security](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html).  The client is never to be trusted and if they are interacting with the database directly then they own the database,  **period**.

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches:

1. install mongodb *without* `--auth` option in trusted environment. Usually it's local network where application, database installed. And servers outside of this network does not have access to mongodb and other resources.
2. install mongodb *with* `--auth` option in environment where mongodb ports not blocked by firewall and everyone can access it.

more details about security you can find [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-MongoSecurity).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a web service interacting with the MongoDB

- The server only deserve rights, you need a regular login to let the server pair access rights with a client using a session. In that way you should avoid rights forging.
- Filter all the clients requests. That is quite easy, the Mongo requests being a jSON, you could either restrict the jSON to a [specific schema](http://json-schema.org/) as well as overloading the request with limitations / restrictions. Note that the server will overload the request using the session's variables. This can be done both for access restrictions but also to avoid the client to send heavy requests which will overload your system.
- Filter back the result, "prune the tree". This could be a last check if for example you agree to return the user's name but not his id. This said, this is more likely one more step  over filtering the client request.
- Use an https secured connection. This will both insure your client to be talking with the right server but also your server to still be talking with the same client (no hijacking in theory).
- Avoid to stack any information together, try using models as much as possible in that way you will gain in clarity but also avoid a sensitive information to be stored at the wrong place.